# Use different Java versions on single Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS server

Tags: java, jenkins

I have Jenkins server which works on Java 8 but, he should make `mvn install`  before deployment. But compiled applications use Java 14.

After Java 14 was installed, Jenkins starting crash with

```
$ sudo service jenkins start Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

With Java 14

```
$ java -version
java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Jenkins not work.

How I can be sure what Jenkins runs with the 8th version but my app compiling with the 14th version without Docker?

Perhaps I can use JRE from 8th and Compiler from 14th somehow? Or use 8th as active and 14th only for compile but how?

Java:

```
$ update-java-alternatives --list
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-14-oracle                 1091       /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle
```

Ubuntu: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Java/Jenkins developer.
Generally, in these cases where multiple program versions are involved, setting the application configuration to use a specific Java version works best, if the application supports that kind of configuration of course. You should check whether you can specify either of Jenkins or the compiler to use certain Java environment.
If that is not possible, then give it a try using environment variables. First, set Java 14 as the default so the compiler gets the latest version. Second, just before starting the Jenkins server, change Java environment temporarily, so that Jenkins sees Java 8 while running,

```sh
$ export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64" \
    && export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH \
    && java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080
```

On another note, using Docker in these scenarios is really a good idea. You should consider that.

I hope this helps.